# MGF problem set up

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Random variable $X$ has the following probability density function:

$f_X(x) = xe^{-x}$ if $x > 0$, 0 otherwise.

Find the moment generating function of X.

Is this the correct set up?
$$ M(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{(t-1)x} \,dx $$

Because when I u-sub, letting $u = x, dv = e^{x(t-1)}dx$, my $uv$ sum tends to $\infty$, which doesn't seem right. I feel like it should be
$$ M(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-(t-1)x} \,dx $$

Edit: Fully solving it:
$$ M(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{(t-1)x} \,dx = xe^{x(t-1)} - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{(t-1)x}}{t-1}$$

$$= xe^{x(t-1)} -  \frac{e^{(t-1)x}}{(t-1)^2}$$ (evalualte both at $\infty, 0$)

If $t < 1$ then the first sum is zero; isn't the second sum also zero because if $x = \infty$, then it tends toward 0 since $t < 1$; if it's 0, then it's just zero. Of course this is incorrect but not sure why.

Comment: Regarding your terminology: $\int u \,dv = uv - \int v \,du$ is integration by parts, not $u$-substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Both integrals might tend to $\infty$, or not, depending on the value of $t$. The integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{(t-1)x} \,dx$$ converges for $t<1$, and the integral  $$\int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-(t-1)x} \,dx$$ converges for $t>1$.

We actually prefer the first behavior: if you want to get moments out of the MGF, you'll be finding $M'(0)$, $M''(0)$, and so on, so you want your MGF to make sense near $0$. So the behavior you're noticing is a confirmation that **you set up the integral right the first time**.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you mind checking my edit?

Comment: You're mixing definite and indefinite integrals in a weird way; when I integrate by parts, I prefer to just fully solve the indefinite integral, then take the boundaries into account. But either way, the term $\frac{e^{(t-1)x}}{(t-1)^2}$ seems correct (maybe some signs are off?), and gives you $\left. \frac{e^{(t-1)x}}{(t-1)^2}\right|_{x=0}^\infty = \frac1{(t-1)^2}$.

Comment: Hmmm. Yes. I got the negative of that last term because don't we need to subtract that expression?

Comment: Yes, sorry; we should actually have $\left. \frac{e^{(t-1)x}}{(t-1)^2}\right|_{x=0}^\infty = -\frac1{(t-1)^2}$, because we're subtracting the value at $x=0$ from the value at $x=\infty$, and then it becomes positive because we want to subtract $\int v \,du$.